# SQL Developer Update 21.2.0.187 Typing delayed

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

This happened in conjunction with updating to 21.2.0.187, but I'm not saying that was the actual problem.

When I type and if I type too quickly, the characters enter in a jumbled manner. If I'm fast enough, it is completely backward.  ie. tceles instead of select

The packages I work in tend to be big, 2500-3500 lines typically. In the past that has been a problem and I've had to set the parser to something bigger. That is still being done with a login script.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the code editor/format settings that "imported" from the last version. I completely uninstalled and reinstalled without "import" from old version and life is much better!